# Permission error when trying to connect SSRS on amazon EC2 to amazon RDS MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to deploy SSRS on amazon EC2 instance and connect it to report DB on RDS. Since amazon RDS doesn't support SSRS, my other option is to open dedicated EC2 instance with MSSQL server on it.

I've tried creating the ReportDB from SSRS configuration utility - getting configuration exception: "User does not have permission to perform this action.". It's most probably caused by insufficient SQL permissions. Amazon doesn't grant you with sa user, only processadmin and setupadmin server roles are granted. In databases you create you gain dbowner.

Also, I've created ReportDB separately and transferred it to the RDS, connected the SSRS to it and when it finally recognized it as a proper ReportDB, I received the same exception.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reporting services will still try and create it's own database, so if you don't have permission to create databases then you are stuck. Using the reporting services configuration tool to create the databases "manually" is still not going to work if you don't have the permission. The setup also involves applying the RSExecRole to the SSRS service account which you also need permission to do.
See the [Check credentials to create and provision the database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157300.aspx) section of this MSDN.

A fallback option is to use Microsoft's [Amazon Machine Image](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/optimized-sql-server-2008-r2-sp1-q1) optimised for SQL Server 2008 R2 and all it's services (including SSRS)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998213/sql-server-reporting-services-for-amazon-rds  please share, if that works ?